# Flipcause Payment Processor Integration

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

Do any of you have experience with the [Flipcause Payment Processor](https://flipcause.org/payment-processing/) and perhaps using it to work with CiviCRM?

Comment: I too am currently interested in an answer to this specific to Joomla, and though you do not mention what CMS you are using with your CiviCRM, there does not seem to be any Extension available that adds this in Joomla as one of the Payment Processor options, sadly. Were you ever able to resolve this question on your own?

Comment: @WebDragon Unfortunately not since I do not require it anymore. I'm on Drupal 7.